# Set default image if img src= null

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 <img src="<%# ReturnEncodedBase64UTF8(Eval("Data")) %>" style="width:100%; height:30%;"/>
```

Hi, I'm new to C# and ASP.NET, I would like to know how do I set the img src to a default img for example ~\images\myimage.png if the img src above return null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use following expression.

```
<img src='<%# Eval("Data") == null ? "~/images/myimage.png" : ReturnEncodedBase64UTF8(Eval("Data")) %>' style="width:100%; height:30%;"/>
```

Besides that if you want to resolve error image using just only html you could use following

```
 <object data="../images/myimage.png" type="image/png" style="width:100%; height:30%;">
         <img src='<%# ReturnEncodedBase64UTF8(Eval("Data")) %>' style="width:100%; height:30%;" />
      </object>
```

Hope that helps.. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I use the first method you provided

Comment: Good then. Best Of Luck. :-)